No `Podfile' found in the project directory despite having the Podfile created on the ios directory
I have an android app developed with flutter that is working and i wanted to extend it to ios so i used the command
flutter create .
that created me the ios folder but then when building I can't because of the dependencies not being installed so i saw that i need to run
pod install
and this is what i get
me@mypc ios % ls
Flutter         Runner          Runner.xcworkspace
Podfile         Runner.xcodeproj    RunnerTests
me@mypc ios % pod install
[!] No 'Podfile' found in the project directory.

I tried uninstall Cocoapods and install again
Delete the folder and tried again
Delete the file and try again with
pod init
